# All permutations of a tree

Tags: serialization, tree, permutation

I need an algorithm that computes **all** possible permutations of a given tree structure, for example:

```
4      3  
 \     |  
  \    2
   \  /  
    1
```

This means, that (4) needs to be ordered before (1), (3) before (2) and (2) before (1).Thus the output should contain all of and not more than the following:

```
[4,3,2,1]  
[3,4,2,1]  
[3,2,4,1]
```

An invalid order would be for example

```
[4,2,3,1]
```

as (2) is before (3), but (2) is the successor of (3) in the graph. Simply computing all permutations and filtering invalid orderings doesn't work for reasons of efficiency.

I don't need the exact code, an idea of how this could generally be done would already be very helpful.

Comment: Doesn't a tree have a single root?  You might have a graph there.  Do you consider 1 to be the root?

Comment: Yes, 1 is the root and 3,4 are the leaves

Comment: What are valid and invalid orderings?

Comment: They why do your permutations not start with 1?  I would expect only prefix, postfix, and infix iteration orders to make sense.

Comment: Edited my post in hope to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody is still interested in this, an algorithm to my problem has already been presented in the 70s by Varol and Rotem in their paper *"An algorithm to generate all topological sorting arrangements"*. 
Actually searching for topological sort would have helped me to find the solution earlier, however, the article can be found here: http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/24/1/83.abstract

Answer (score 1):

This problem is to topological sort a directed graph.
It could be resolved by DFS with time complexity O(E+V). 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: But as I understand it, topological sorting only gives me one possible solution but I need all of them.